# Using intents in android is causing problems between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-intentservice

I have run into a problem. I have an animation that is going in my first activity, and a countdown timer in my second activity. When I set the countdown timer the value is passed back into my first activity which begins a new countdown activity, but the animation stops. How can I pass the value of the countdown timer to my MainActivity while still Maintaining the animation in my main activity.

Here is my code for the intent in my SecondActivity that is being passed to my MainActivity. Im not sure what code to show because I am not sure what the cause of the problem is.

```
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //put your logic here to set the time with hourPicked and minPicked variables
            timer = new CounterClass((hours * 60 * 1000) + (minutes * 1000), 1000);
            String hms = String.format(("%02d:%02d"), hours, minutes);
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SleepTimer.this, MainActivity.class);
            String TimeValue = (hms);
            intent.putExtra("TimeValue", TimeValue);
            startActivity(intent);
            timer.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you come back to mainactivity from second activity,then it will be recreated know so only its beginning from start.

Comment: Could you show some code. Im not quite sure what your getting at.

Comment: Don't do what @MeetTitan says. There's no guarantee the first activity will still exist when you return from the second activity, and keeping a reference to an activity may actually cause a memory leak. Use a dialog instead of a second activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare String hms globally and onclick of button finish the SleeoTimer activity.and access global variable **hms** at MainActivity in SleepTimer Activity create field as `public static String hms;`
and in MainActivity use it as `SleepTimer.hms`

```
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //put your logic here to set the time with hourPicked and minPicked variables
        timer = new CounterClass((hours * 60 * 1000) + (minutes * 1000), 1000);
         hms = String.format(("%02d:%02d"), hours, minutes);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
       SleepTimer.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all how do you declare a global variable, and what would the code in my main activity look like then

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your animation code on Activity Oncreate,OnPause and also in OnResume as per your requirement.